# UIWebView delegate method LoadFinished not invoked

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I am loading a web page in the web view, the view loads properly but the LoadFinished delegate method is not invoked, all other delegate methods are invoked properly. Here is my code

```
public partial class TestViewController
{
    public TestViewController(){}
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        MyWebViewDelegate webDelegate = new MyWebViewDelegate();
        myWebView.Delegate = webDelegate;

        string webUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/"
        if (Connectivity.CheckForInternetConnection() && webUrl != null)
        {
            myWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(webUrl)));
            ProgressView.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressView.Hide();
        }
        myWebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
    }
}

public class MyWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{
    public MyWebViewDelegate() : base(){}

    public override void LoadFailed(UIWebView webView, NSError error)
    {
        ProgressView.Hide();
    }

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
    {
        ProgressView.Hide();
    }
}
```

I need to detect the load finish, to hide the progress view, But I don't know what is wrong with my code Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Silly question, but are you absolutely sure it has actually 'finished' loading? How long have you left it etc? because that delegate method according to the documentation is sitll perfectly valid, it's not been depreciated.

Comment: I left it for nearly 15 minutes in a 4G network, but the page loaded just in 3 seconds.

Comment: are you assigning an event to 'myWebView.LoadingFinished' anywhere else in your code at all?

Comment: No, I am not doing any assignment.

Comment: The most common reason that the delegate class would fire some if not all methods, is if at some point you're trying to assign (+=) to one of the controls events that is usually handled by the delegate class in which case it overwrites it.

Comment: No, I gave the entire code of my view controller, there is no such assignment statements.